# Fetch data from SQLite only contains single data row

Tags: android, sqlite

In my app i am **storing data to SQLite**, and now i am trying to **fetch that data from SQLite to activity**.

as per requirement i just have to store single data at a time and my table will contain only single data row not more than one row.

so I want if table has data row then **fetch data and show in form** in **onCreate(..)** of **LoginActivity.java**

**Getting:**

```
The method SelectData(String) in the type myDBClass is not applicable for the arguments ()
```

**myDBClass.java:**

```
// Select Data
    public String[] SelectData(String strOperatorID) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

         try {
            String arrData[] = null;    

             SQLiteDatabase db;
             db = this.getReadableDatabase(); // Read Data

             Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[] { "*" }, 
                        "OperatorID=?",
                        new String[] { String.valueOf(strOperatorID) }, null, null, null, null);

                if(cursor != null)
                {
                    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                        arrData = new String[cursor.getColumnCount()];

                        arrData[0] = cursor.getString(0); // DeviceID
                        arrData[1] = cursor.getString(1); // EmailID
                        arrData[2] = cursor.getString(2); // Event
                        arrData[3] = cursor.getString(3); // Operator
                        arrData[4] = cursor.getString(4); // EventOperator
                    }
                }

                cursor.close();
                db.close();
                return arrData;

         } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
         }
    }
```

**LoginActivity.java:-**

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity  {
    .................


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        btnLogout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogout);
        btnCamera = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCamera);
        btnGallery = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnGallery);

            txtDeviceID = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtDeviceID);
            txtEmailID = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtEmailID);      
            txtEvent = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtEvent);  
            txtOperative = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtOperative);
            txtEventOperator = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtEventOperator);

             Intent intent = getIntent();
             deviceID = intent.getStringExtra("deviceID");
             emailID = intent.getStringExtra("emailID");
             event = intent.getStringExtra("name"); 
             operative = intent.getStringExtra("firstName");

             txtDeviceID.setText(deviceID);
             txtEmailID.setText(emailID);
             txtEvent.setText(event);
             txtOperative.setText(operative);
             txtEventOperator.setText(event + "  " + operative);

             strEvent = txtEvent.getText().toString();
             strOperative = txtOperative.getText().toString();

                // Dialog
                final AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                AlertDialog ad = adb.create();

                // new Class DB
                final myDBClass myDb = new myDBClass(this);

                // Save Data
                long saveStatus = myDb.InsertData(
                            txtDeviceID.getText().toString(),
                            txtEmailID.getText().toString(),
                            txtEvent.getText().toString(),
                            txtOperative.getText().toString(),
                            txtEventOperator.getText().toString()
                            );

                if(saveStatus <=  0)
                {
                  ad.setMessage("Error!! ");
                  ad.show();
                  return;
                }   

                // Show Data
                String arrData[] = myDb.SelectData();
                if(arrData != null)
                {
                    txtDeviceID.setText(arrData[1]);
                    txtEmailID.setText(arrData[2]);
                    txtEvent.setText(arrData[3]);
                    txtOperative.setText(arrData[4]);
                    txtEventOperator.setText(arrData[5]);
                }  

 if(txtEvent.getText().toString().equals("") && txtOperative.getText().toString().equals(""))
                {
                    Intent intentCall = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, LicenseListActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intentCall);
                }
              }
```

Comment: Why are you using a database if you're only going to store a single row?  Its just about the least efficient and silliest design you can make.

Comment: @kalyanpvs not able to run my program, because getting: The method SelectData(String) in the type myDBClass is not applicable for the arguments ()

Comment: @Moon You need to learn java first..it clearly saying call method with String argument but you are passing nothing..

Comment: @kalyanpvs i just want to know what are the changes required in my code to get data from sqlite table row

Comment: @Moon do you know the operatorId in your code..if then pass it to method..

Comment: @kalyanpvs try to understand, operatorid would not be the same everytime

Comment: @Moon what data is present in database..and what data you want to retrieve.based on your operatorId it will return data from db.its same or not same data its based on up to your requirement

Comment: @kalyanpvs i just want to fetch data from that single row, no matter for me what is the operatorid, if data exist then show, that's what i want to do...

Comment: ok...i will post code..change like that

Comment: @Moon posted change your code like that

Comment: @kalyanpvs bro where is code, i was in mid of meeting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the op requirement..
change your method like this..

```
public String[] SelectData() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    try {
        String arrData[] = new String[5];

        SQLiteDatabase db;
        db = this.getReadableDatabase(); // Read Data

        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME, null, null, null, null,
                null, null);

        if (cursor != null) {
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {

                arrData[0] = cursor.getString(0); // DeviceID
                arrData[1] = cursor.getString(1); // EmailID
                arrData[2] = cursor.getString(2); // Event
                arrData[3] = cursor.getString(3); // Operator
                arrData[4] = cursor.getString(4); // EventOperator
            }
        }

        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        return arrData;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: why are we using new String[5]; in place of null ?

Comment: ok..i haven't seen this line  arrData = new String[cursor.getColumnCount()]; i think you are perfoming on null object

Comment: @Moon thats also not good idea if the cursor contain one row it will throw ArraryIndexOutOf Bound exception

Comment: so what should i need to do ?

Comment: whenever i am removing my app from TaskList and launching again that time not getting values

Comment: posted bro check please

Answer (score 0):

Your `SelectData` method takes a String argument (`strOperatorID`) but you are calling it with no argument, so obviously it cannot be found.

By the way you should respect Java naming conventions for your methods (i.e. not starting with upper case character)

Answer (score 0):

```
public String[] SelectData() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    try {
        String arrData[] = new String[5];

        SQLiteDatabase db;
        db = this.getReadableDatabase(); // Read Data

        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME, null, null, null, null,
                null, null);

        if (cursor != null) {
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
do{

                arrData[0] = cursor.getString(0); // DeviceID
                arrData[1] = cursor.getString(1); // EmailID
                arrData[2] = cursor.getString(2); // Event
                arrData[3] = cursor.getString(3); // Operator
                arrData[4] = cursor.getString(4); // EventOperator
          } while (cur.moveToNext()); 
 }
        }


        return arrData;

    } catch (Exception e) {

        return null;
    }finally{
  cursor.close();
        db.close();
}
```